# how to stop testsuite when a testcase threw out NoSuchElementException

Tags: selenium, nosuchelementexception

I put 4 testcases into one testsuite and in each testcase I have code to catch  the NoSuchElementException.
I want:
if any one testcase threw out NoSuchElementException, the testsuite execution should stop.

For Example, if first testcase throws NoSuchElementException, then testcase 2&3&4 should not execute anymore. if the second testcase throw out a NoSuchElementException, then testcase 3&4 should not execute anymore.

Comment: the ruby implementation used to have a `--fail-fast` option, but it seems removed.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specifed the language. If Java you can use TestNG framework and `dependOnMethods` annotations. Here is simple example: http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/testng-tutorial-7-dependency-test/